# Is there an equivalent implementation in Vanilla javascript of using delay and queue combination in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, queue, delay

I want to find a way to implement delay and queue combinations (jquery) in Vanilla javascript.
I am looking for implementation instead of using setTimeout function multiple times.

For example,

```
conuntBox 
  .appendTo(el)
  .delay(idx * 300)
  .queue(function(){$(this).addClass('active');});
});
```

Comment: `setTimeout()` is the way to do this.